# How do you darken UIScrollView's overflow?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Suppose you wanna implement the same functionality iOS's camera 'Zoom & Crop' has... in which you can scroll and crop an image.

Any section of the picture that exceeds the size of the crop area gets grayed out.
I'm trying to replicate exactly that. Provided that the flag 'clipToBounds' is set to NO, you can get the whole subview to get displayed.

However, i'm finding it a bit hard to gray out the UIScrollView's subviews overflow.

How would you implement that?. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by...:

- Adding a new helper class, 'ApertureOverlay' (subclass of UIView), with the following code:

  > - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
  >     {
  >
  >   if(CGRectEqualToRect(_apertureRect, CGRectZero) == NO)
  >
  >   {
  >
  >   ```
  >   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  >
  >   CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, false);
  >
  >   CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  >   CGContextFillRect(context, _apertureRect);
  >
  >   CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);
  >   ```
  >
  >   }
  >
  > }
- ApertureOverlay has a background with the alpha byte set to 50%.

  [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.5f]];

So far... al we've got is a view with transparent background, and a white rectangle (drawn with _apertureRect position + size).

After implementing this class, i've set up the 'mask' attribute of the ScrollView, which contains the image inside.

```
[[self layer] setMask:[_apertureOverlayView layer]];
```

That's it!. If you update the ApertureOverlay's '_apertureRect' attribute, you'll need to call 'setNeedsDisplay', so it gets redrawn.

One more thing. By setting the antialias to false (ApertureOverlay)... things work pretty smooth.

Comment: Sorry. I cannot share the full source for that. But the core is what's already pasted up there.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a subclass of `UIView` that is semi-transparent in the overflow region and transparent in the "crop" region and placing it over your `UIScrollView` and extending it out to cover the overflow.

The main methods you need to implement are `initWithFrame`:

```
#define kIDZAlphaOverlayDefaultAlpha 0.75

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        mAlpha = kIDZAlphaOverlayDefaultAlpha;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:mAlpha];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Don't miss out the `userInteractionEnabled = NO` otherwise the scroll view will not sees events.

and `drawRect`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{    
    CGRect apertureRect = /* your crop rect */;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    /* draw the transparent rect */
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextFillRect(context, apertureRect);
    /* draw a white border */
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, apertureRect);
}
```

The important point here is the `kCGBlendModeCopy` this allows us to draw (or cut) a transparent rectangle in a semi-transparent background.

If you want to can make the transparent rectangle a rounded rectangle, and include a preview of the cropped image and end up with something like the screen below:

[image: Screenshot of IDZAlphaOverlay in action]

Sorry I can't share all the code for the screen shot. It's from a client project :-(

Comment: I notice you did not accept this as an answer. Were you unable to get it to work? Do you need more assistance?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up!. I couldn't build it, since the method  'CGContextFrameRect' seems to be missing. I ended up solving this by means of Core Graphics (CGContextFillRect). I've added a custom overlay view, and i've used the CALayer of that view as a mask in the ImageView CALayer. (That's the reason why i didn't click the accept, sorry about that, and thanks again!)